# Подключение микрофона и запись голоса

Tags: windows, delphi

Мне нужно сделать программу, чтоб голос был как пароль, и я не знаю, как подключить к программе микрофон, чтоб он записывал голос когда надо!

Comment: Уточните платформу и средство разработки.

Comment: @MOHAX, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: Голос, как пароль - это уже искуственный интелект, который является одим из самых сложных вещей в программировании...

Comment: может уже и существуют написанные нейронные сети, которые можно обучить разпознавать звук, но такой пароль всё равно не лучший вариант.

Comment: 1) Делфи 7, 2) я не прошу выполнить полностью программу, я просто хочу узнать как микрофон к программе присоеденить, 3) У нас в универе говорят, что это самый простой способ динамического метода, у меня в универе и по пальцу делали и по почерку идентификации...

Comment: ну поиграться можно, например, в дрончике есть неплохое апи для работы со звуком, может можно как-то оттуда вытягивать тембр и чет еще и делать диапазон - ключ. А потом по нему авторизовать =)

Comment: Лол в универе наверняка используют готовые программы и оборудование. Или они через программу отпечатки берут? На то чтобы создать программу хотябы для распознания голоса, Вам потребуется лет 10 не меньше. Систему распознания речи, текста, лица, отпечатков пальцев создавал большой коллектив(и не один, а несколько) и не один десяток лет!

Comment: я говорю как есть, мне смысла придумывать нету..

Comment: @MOHAX, не поленитесь отредактировать вопрос и обозначьте вашу конкретную задачу. В текущей формулировке вопрос звучит как "дайти к0д!!!1".

Comment: @MOHAX Хаха ну как бЭ это чисто лекционный материал. Можете залезть в книжку ну или в гугл например. Единственное что могу посоветовать установите с сайта ну или просто ознакомьтесь http://bm.speechpro.com/bioscud/

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрите на [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/). Это библиотека по работе со звуком на разных платформах, включает в том числе и запись звука.

Если разработка под голый Windows, то есть API: [waveInOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743847(v=vs.85).aspx) и т.п. А если под .NET, то есть опять же хорошая библиотека [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/), которая упрощает работу со звуком в Windows.